# How to have changing range in Google Sheet graph

Tags: google-sheets

I am using sheets for tracking weight loss. I want my graph to show the data points but have the x range set to whatever the latest day data was entered, so that I do not have months long x axis in the beginning.

The current range is

```
C27: D203
```

I want it to be something like

```
C27: D (=COUNT (D28: D203)+27)
```

I just don't know how to reference it since it wants a Cell not whatever I'm giving it.

Comment: I have to wonder if the [WebApps StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 32960 people would disagree with you https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTTeP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT("C27:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(D28:D)+27, 4))
```

Comment: It says to enter a valid range. I assume it wants an actual cell. https://i.imgur.com/fI23dbJ.png

Comment: @NinjaMastor chart does not allow indirect ranges so you need to use the formula form answer in your sheet (some free columns) and then build a chart from there